# WP Single.php If and elseif statement execution

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php if (in_category('3')) {
        $args = array(
        'cat' => 'Japan',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_key' => 'japan_id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        } elseif (in_category('5')) {
        $args = array(
        'cat' => 'Borneo',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_key' => 'borneo_id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );}?>

        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?> 
        <?php $status = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'status', true); ?><?php $finishdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'finishdate', true); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> " rel="favourite" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-thumbnail'); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php
       // Reset Post Data
       wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Hi all, I'm trying to do a if and elseif to check :

- If this single post belongs to category 3
- Get info of this post (category name, order by meta value number of this meta_key in ASC order
- Else if this single post belongs to category 5
- Get info of this post ... in ASC order

However, i keep getting error that "Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in ... on line...." I want to display all the featured thumbnails of all the posts that are from the same category as the Single Post.

Example of SIngle Post : http://ethanlimphotos.com/2012/04/19/orangutan-grabs-legs
The featured thumbnails scroll should be displayed like this http://ethanlimphotos.com
I want the featured thumbnails scroll on the Index Page to work on the Single page too. 
Please help, thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why almost everyone is creating a new object when they want to do custom loops :) Is this because this is the way you saw an example, or you have different reasons(I'm just really curious :) ).

Anyway, the way I go when I need a custom loop is to just call `query_posts()`, use the normal `have_posts()` and `the_post()` and then reset the query variable with `wp_reset_query()`. So here's how your code will look like when you use that approach:

```
<?php if (in_category('3')) {
    $args = array(
    'cat' => 'Japan',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'meta_key' => 'japan_id',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    query_posts( $args );
} elseif ( in_category( '5' ) ) {
    $args = array(
        'cat' => 'Borneo',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_key' => 'borneo_id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    query_posts( $args );
}?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
    <?php $status = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'status', true); ?><?php $finishdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'finishdate', true); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> " rel="favourite" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-thumbnail'); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
// Reset the query data
wp_reset_query();?>
```